# What does it mean for an allocator to be stateless?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

What does it mean for an allocator to be stateless? I realize that std::allocator is a wrapper around malloc, and has no state of its own. At the same time, malloc does its own bookkeeping, so one could say that all std::allocator instances make use of a single state.

How would I go about implementing a pool allocator without state? If not the allocator, what would keep the current state of memory?

Could someone formally define what state means in this context?

Comment: Does calling it "internally stateless" make it clearer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

State means that the instances of class have mutable information in them. Stateless means that they do not have it. Stateless classes do not have non-static data members.

You can make pool allocator to be stateless by using some mutual external state (a pool) that is same for all pool allocators of that type.

Comment: In this case, how can I ensure thread safety using only c++ language feature? If each call to allocate or deallocate could block on a mutex, would this not be a problem?

Comment: There are several possibilities how to achieve lock-less thread safety of allocator. For example it could allocate from different portions of pool based on std::thread::id of current thread.

Comment: This feature is universally supported by current compilers and part of c++03 standard?

Comment: No. C++03 does not have threads at all. Threads and thread safety is totally implementation and platform-specific in C++03. You have to use POSIX or Windows threads directly or rely on third party libraries like boost when using C++03

Comment: It is not by default. With gcc you have to compile with option -pthreads to achieve that malloc is thread safe. With Visual C you have to use one of /MT, /MTd, MD or /MDd to make malloc thread safe.

Comment: I find the last sentence of this answer rather unclear, boarding on circular: allocators allocate from the same pool if and only if they share that pool state, but this does not clarify what it means to be external. Certainly if every allocator had a pointer to a pool that may or may not be the same pointer as in another allocator of the same type, then that allocator does have state. Wouldn't it be simpler to equate "state" to having non-static data members? Certainly, without those there can be no state; on the other hand if they do exist, more than likely they serve to record state.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I add the clarification that stateless classes do not have non-static data members that I thought to be obvious. As of what is unclear about state of pool being same for all instances of stateless allocator I do not understand.

Comment: My confusion came from the final "that allocate objects from that pool". This phrase appears to restrict the claim (in a circular way): it appears to leave the door open for te possibility of allocators _of the same type_ that nonetheless differ in their external state because they allocate from different pools. That could only be possible due to non-static data members, and would contradict my idea of what "external" and "stateless" mean, so adding that phase just makes me confused. Clearer would be "You can make pool allocator type stateless... the same for all pool allocators of that type."

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen thanks, your wording is perhaps better indeed,

Answer (score 3):

The allocator object himself is discouraged to be stateful. This means if you create an instance of `std::allocator` (or your own), this instance should not contain any info about allocated blocks etc - this info must be `static` and shared across all `std::allocator` instances. Breaking this rule may lead to undefined behavior in STL libraries.

For example, look at `std::list::splice`: it removes and interval of elements from one `std::list` and insert into other. Really nothing done with contained elements (no copying etc) - this method just rearranges internal pointers. So, if `std::allocator` instance #1 (in list #1) know something, what dont know `std::allocator` instance #2 (in list #2) ? These elements will be lost, memleaked, spontaneously deleted or whatever..

A good reading about such things on STL is "Effective STL", Scott Meyers

Comment: This may have been the case for C++03, but C++11 explicitly supports stateful allocators.

Comment: "Breaking this rule may lead to undefined behavior in STL libraries." Can you link a doc page that states that please

Comment: @Felipe "All custom allocators also must be stateless (until c++11)" http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator For c++11 need to use special mechanics to transfer pointer ownership between allocators.

Comment: Thanks, do you know by chance if c++11 state mechanics are implemented in gcc 5.1.0?

Comment: @Felipe im not sure this does apply to default(std) allocators since i think they are stateless.